# Error while adding custom rules

Tags: c#, sonarqube

I am getting the following error message while adding custom quality rules in SonarQube 6.5 for the C# language:

> Technical importer for the MSbuild SonarQube  Scanner cannot be used.

Comment: So you added a custom rule in SonarQube (derived from a rule template), and then ran the MSbuild Scanner? Which rule did you derive from? Is this the only line of log you got? (please edit your question to add additional information)

Comment: I have received xml file of rule from client and just login to sonarqube with admin privileges....click on Quality Profiles and provide name, language as C#, select xml file and click on create button it gives a red banner mentioning that Technical importer for the MSbuild SonarQube Scanner cannot be used.